# module 'pyrebase' has no attribute 'initialize_app',

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, pyrebase

I am trying to import pyrebase but it hasn't been importing properly. I finally got it to import properly but am now stuck on the error "module 'pyrebase' has no attribute 'initialize_app'".

This is my code

```
import pyrebase

config = {
"apiKey": "apiKey",
"authDomain": "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
"databaseURL": "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
"storageBucket": "projectId.appspot.com"

}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
```

I have tried pip3 install pyrebase4, pip3 install pycryptodome, and if I do pip3 install pyrebase it has conflicts with pyrebase4's requirements and also does not run properly on its own.

Maybe there is still an issue with the pyrebase import?